# SQLite sorting order by asc

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

I am using `SQLite` with `python-2.7` . In my `SQLite` database i contains a `date` field that stored date in `dd-MM-yyyy` format like that.

```
31/02/2018
30/02/2017
01/06/2018
```

How can i sort it ascending order.

Comment: You can't easily do this, because in SQLite all dates are stored as plain text.  I would recommend storing your dates in the format `year/month/day`.  Then, they will sort as you want.  There is a workaround here, but it would be a very ugly query, and not really worth your time long term.

Comment: @macson taylor, are you using pure SQLite or are you using some other language along side it?

Comment: @Mr.Zeus I am using python 2.7 with sqlite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this query:

```
SELECT date(substr(`date_column`,7,4)||'-'||substr(`date_column`,4,2)||'-'||substr(`date_column`,1,2)) as text_date FROM `table` order by text_date asc
```

Answer (score 1):

first get all rows with

```
connect = sqlite3.connect('datanase_file')
cursor = connect.execute('select date from table_name')
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

then convert the dates to seconds from epoch so you can sort them

```
for row in rows:
    t = time.strptime(row[0],'%d/%m/%Y')
    converted_time = time.mktime(t)
```

then add converted_time column with type INT to your database.

then update your database with

```
connect.execute('''UPDATE table_name SET converted_time = ? WHERE date = ?''',
               (converted_time, row[0]))
```

then you can sort it with any program.